# Can't insert the value NULL into column in EF 6.1.3

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I created a table in SQL Server Management Studio with two columns, `FacilityId` is the primary key and not null. After the design, I manually added the first row.

However when I insert the new record into the table programmatically in C# code I get this error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'FacilityId', table 'xxxxxxxx'; column does not allow nulls.

My table in code:

```
public class MyURL
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Column("FacilityId")]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    [Column("Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

To add new record by the below code:

```
public void AddNewUrl(int id, string url)
{
        using (MyUrlContext context = new MyUrlContext())
        {
            context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(context);
            var data = GetNewUrl(id, url);
            SaveContextAfterAddingNewRecord(context, data);
        }
}

public virtual void SaveContextAfterAddingNewRecord(MyUrlContext context, MyURL data)
{
        context.MyEndpoints.Add(data);
        context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And

```
public class MyUrlContext : DbContext
{
    public MyUrlContext():base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyUrlContext>(null);
    }

    public DbSet<MyURL> MyEndpoints { get; set; }
}
```

So what is wrong?

**EDIT:**

The db/table structure.

[image: facilityid]

Also, I do have the value provided.

See the image:

[image: ex]

I am sure that the identity property is off.

[image: 3]

**EDIT2:**

The SS profiler indicated

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[TableName]([Url])
VALUES (@0)
SELECT [FacilityID]
FROM [dbo].[TableName]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [FacilityID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ',@0=N'sdfsdf'
```

Comment: in Debug mode check your 'data' object, does he has id?

Comment: you can put AutoIncrement to ID column

Comment: @eminach. No, it doesn't have ID and I don't want it.

Comment: Then, try to put, autoincrement to id column in that table

Comment: So what does the SQL statement look like?

Comment: @GertArnold. I am not sure how to generate the SQL statement. I use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework). The result is something like `SELECT 
    [Extent1].[FacilityId] AS [FacilityId], 
    [Extent1].[Url] AS [Url]
    FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE 163 = [Extent1].[FacilityId]`

Comment: The INSERT statement of course. Just look in the SS profiler.

Comment: @GertArnold, please see my updated thread about SS profiler.

Comment: Well, according to EF, `FacilityId` is an identity column.

Comment: @GertArnold, so what is wrong? I couldn't figure it out. Should I redesign the database just let auto identity on and forget the `FacilityId` as the primary key?

Comment: You should figure out why EF doesn't pickup the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute. Is there any additional fluent mapping involved?

Comment: @GertArnold, no. It is not code first EF, I designed the db at Sql Ser Management Studio. So I don't have additional fluent mapping. I only have the POCO class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally reslove it under the help of somebody in the team. The code itself is nothing wrong. The problem is that I developed the project as a class library and add it to an asp.net MVC application. The web application is a DNX 4.5.1 project. Because my original dll had some defect I believe, although I updated it, the DNX 4.5.1 framework couldn't find it. It always looked the original dll in the cache.

The right action is to push the dll to the Nuget server, then add to the web application. So the dll version can be incremented automatically.

So whatever I played the attribute, it just is not working. Hopefully in the next release of Visual Studio 2015 release, the issue can be resloved.

Answer (score 0):

What's the exact definition of `FacilityID` in your database table?

Is it defined as an **`IDENTITY`** column (to make SQL Server assign values automatically)?
If so, then you need to use `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` in your EF model.

If it's *not* defined as an identity column, then you **must provide** a value when you insert a new row.

**Update:** if that column is *not* an identity column (which seems to be the case), I'd recommend to entirely remove that `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute from your model class:

```
public class MyURL
{
    [Key]
    [Column("FacilityId")]
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    [Column("Url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It is not an identity column and I did provided a value. See the edited body.

Comment: @Love: as the SQL Server Profiler log shows - there's no value for `FacilityID` being provided. Since this is *not* an identity column, I would suggest you remove that `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute completely from your model class

Comment: I removed it, but nothing changed. The profiler is still same.

Comment: By the way, this is a dll. I can insert the new record in the unit test of dll project even with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`. But it failed in an asp.net mvc project when I add the dll to the controller. Not sure whether it is the issue.